# How do I overload the Equals operator in my class so that Queue.Contains() works?

Tags: c#, containers, overloading, equals

I've created a class State.  For a Queue of State objects, I want to test whether the Queue already contains a State object of equal value.  Two State objects, which each contain a 2D boolean array, are equal when all values of the arrays are equal and in the same order.

Here is my relevant code:

```
public class State {
   Boolean[,] grid = new Boolean[4,4];

   Public State(Boolean[,] passedGrid){ //Constructor
       grid = Array.Copy(passedGrid, grid, 16);
   }

   public bool Equals(State s2){ //Overloaded equals operator
         for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                 for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                      if (grid[x, y] != s2.grid[x, y]){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

}

    public void testContains(Boolean[] testArray) {
        Queue<State> testQueue = new Queue<State>();
        State s1 = new State(testArray);
        State s2 = new State(testArray);
        testQueue.Enqueue(s1);
        Boolean b = testQueue.Contains(s2);
    }
```

Unfortunately, when testContains() is called and I check the value of testQueue.Contains(s2) at the end, it still says the test is false, even though they have identical array values and the Equals operator was overloaded to test for that.  What do I have to do or change to get Queue.Contains to work with my object?  I read somewhere that getHashCode() is recommended to be overloaded whenever Equals is overloaded.  Do I need to do that in this case?  If so, what should the overloaded getHashCode() do?

Comment: Your Equals method is not overriding the base class implementation instead a new method is being created. Try adding the override keyword to the Equals method and then see if it works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override Equals, you need to use `object` as the parameter type and the keyword `override`.

so you can try something like

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as State);
    }
    public bool Equals(State s2)
    { //Overloaded equals operator 
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if (grid[x, y] != s2.grid[x, y])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You should probably also include test for `null`

Have a look at [How to define value equality for a class or struct (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type)

Comment: `obj as State` might return null.

Comment: @SeanU, added that to the anser that the OP should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should `override` *Equals*.

```
public override bool Equals(object s2)
{
    //implementation
}
```

For better practice, you should implement some other interfaces like: `IEquatable` `IEqualtable<State>` and the method `GetHashCode`. The override `Equals` method and the `Equals` methods in `IEquatable` `IEqualtable<T>` can share a common private `Equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing override keyword

```
   public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
       // fill in the body
    }
```

Comment: When I did this, I get the error "no suitable method found to override"

Comment: This cannot happen as all classes by default inherit object class anyway try to inherit object class explicitly.

Comment: Also make sure to copy my code exactly and fill in the body please.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to override virtual method defined on class `Object`:

```
public override Equals(object other)
{
   if(other is State)
        return Equals((State)other); 
   return base.Equals(other);
}
```

You need to use this generic overload because this method is used by `Contains` method and simply adding instance method with the same name is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code which will work for you just fine:

```
    public class State : Object {
   Boolean[,] grid = new Boolean[4,4];

   public State(Boolean[,] passedGrid){ //Constructor
       Array.Copy(passedGrid, grid, 16);
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object s2){ //Overloaded equals operator
         for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                 for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                      if (grid[x, y] != ((State)s2).grid[x, y]){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

}


    class Program
    {
        Boolean[,] testArray = new Boolean[4, 4];

        public static void Main()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.testContains(p.testArray);
        }

        public void testContains(Boolean[,] testArray)
        {
            Queue<State> testQueue = new Queue<State>();
            State s1 = new State(testArray);
            State s2 = new State(testArray);
            testQueue.Enqueue(s1);
            Boolean b = testQueue.Contains(s2);
            //b is true here
        }

    }
}
```

Also, please look into below link to get guidelines for overriding Equals method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Code which overrides `Equals(Object)` should also override `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

For a class type to define a custom equality relation, the following should apply:

1. The class should be immutable, and must not encapsulate mutable state.  It is acceptable for an immutable class to hold references to mutable objects if and only if such references are used only to encapsulate the *identities* of such objects or immutable attributes thereof.

   The class must override `bool Equals(Object Other)` so as to return `true` when `Other` is an equivalent instance of the class (an instance is equivalent to itself; for mutable types, an instance is the *only* thing that's equivalent to itself).

   The class must override `int GetHashCode()` such that any two equivalent instances will return the same value, and preferably so that two arbitrarily-selected non-equivalent instances will be unlikely to return the same value.

   If the class is sealed, it may implement `IEquatable` for its own type in addition to doing the above.  Unsealed classes should not implement `IEquatable`.

With regard to your particular class, I would suggest that since there are only 65,536 possible distinct instances, you should simply store an `Integer` which identifies which combination of bits is used, compare that in `Equals`, and return it for `GetHashCode`.